# $\|TS\|_1 \leq \|T\|_2\|S\|_2 $for any $T$,$S$ in Schatten Class p=2

Tags: functional-analysis

Show $\|TS\|_1 \leq \|T\|_2\|S\|_2 $for any $T$,$S$ in Schatten Class p=2

From holder inequality we have $\sum\mu_n(S)\mu_n(T)\leq\|T\|_2\|S\|_2$

But I don't know if LHS exceeds $\sum\mu_n(TS)$

Can someone show me a hint or answer?

Comment: What does $\mu_n$ means here ?

Comment: singular values of the operator -ie $\mu_n(T)= \sqrt {\lambda_n (T^*T)}$ where $\lambda_n(.)$ is the eigenvalues arranged in non increasing order

Comment: just realised it's answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722921/how-to-prove-ab-1-leq-a-2-b-2-trace-class-and-hilbert-schmidt-opera?rq=1